Implement Edit and Delete functions using buttons
I have this HTML file of a website that includes a form to enter recipes and display them below. Every recipe has a title, an ingredients section and an instructions section and every recipe must have its own Edit and Delete buttons.
I'm currently trying to make the editRecipe function and I already have the deleteRecipe function.
However, I haven't been able to set the deleteRecipe function to the delete button and therefore the recipe doesn't get deleted when I click on the button. In other words, the delete button is not working.
Here are the HTML and the JS codes I have:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Recipe Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Recipe Book</h1>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="recipe-form">
            <h2>Add a Recipe</h2>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Recipe Title">
            <label for="ingredients">Ingredients:</label>
            <input type="text" id="ingredients" placeholder="Ingredients (comma-separated)">
            <label for="instructions">Instructions:</label>
            <textarea id="instructions" placeholder="Preparation Instructions"></textarea>
            <button id="add-recipe-btn">Add Recipe</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="recipe-list">
        <h2>Recipes</h2>
        <ul id="recipes"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


The JS code:
const recipes = [];

var indexOfRecipeToBeEdited = -1

// Declared a flag to set the edit mode
var isEditMode = false

document.getElementById('add-recipe-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    const ingredients = document.getElementById("ingredients").value;
    const instructions = document.getElementById('instructions').value;
    console.log(title, ingredients, instructions)
    if (!isEditMode) {
        addRecipe({ title, ingredients, instructions });
    }
    else {
        editRecipeDetails({ title, ingredients, instructions})
        isEditMode = false
    }
    displayRecipes();
    clearInputFields();
});

function editRecipeDetails(recipe) {
    const {title, ingredients, instructions} = recipe
    recipes[indexOfRecipeToBeEdited].title = title;
    recipes[indexOfRecipeToBeEdited].ingredients = ingredients;
    recipes[indexOfRecipeToBeEdited].instructions = instructions;
}

function clearInputFields() {
    // Write your code here for task 1
    document.getElementById("title").value = "";
    document.getElementById("ingredients").value = "";
    document.getElementById("instructions").value = "";
}

// Add the new recipe to the recipes array
function addRecipe(recipe) {
    const {title, ingredients, instructions} = recipe;
    if (title && ingredients && instructions) {
        recipes.push(recipe);
        displayRecipes();
    }
}

// Display Recipes
function displayRecipes() {
    // Write your code here for task 3
    const recipesList = document.getElementById('recipes');
    recipesList.innerHTML = '';
    for (const recipe of recipes) {
        const recipeItem = document.createElement('li');
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');  // here's the delete button being created
        let editButton = document.createElement('button');
        recipeItem.innerHTML =
        `<p><b>${recipe.title}</b></p> 
        <p><b>Ingredients: </b> ${recipe.ingredients}</p> 
        <p><b>Instructions: </b> ${recipe.instructions}</p>
        `
        deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
        editButton.innerText = 'Edit';
        for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length ; i++) {
            deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                deleteRecipe(i);  // Here I tried to pass the function to the button, no success
            })
        }
        recipesList.appendChild(recipeItem);
        recipesList.appendChild(editButton);  // I still don't have the edit function
        recipesList.appendChild(deleteButton);
    }
}

// Edit the recipe object when the Edit button is clicked
function editRecipe(index) {
    isEditMode = true

}

// Delete the recipe object when the Delete button is clicked
function deleteRecipe(index){
    if (index >= 0 && index < recipes.length) {
        recipes.splice(index, 1); // Remove 1 element at the specified index
        displayRecipes();
        console.log(recipes)
        clearInputFields();
        isEditMode = false;     
        
    }
}

How can I make the delete function work when the button is clicked? How can the Edit function be?
TIA

Delete button
This inner for-loop in your displayRecipes function is problematic:
for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length ; i++) {
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        deleteRecipe(i);  // Here I tried to pass the function to the button, no success
    })
}

You're binding deleteRecipe multiple times to a single button. Basically whenever you click a delete button, it's calling deleteRecipe for all recipe indices. The only reason you don't actually see it delete everything is because deleting while iterating through an array will naturally cause you to skip indices.
Instead of having this inner for-loop, you should just add the event listener once. I.e. just change it to this:
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    deleteRecipe(i);  // Here I tried to pass the function to the button, no success
})

Of course, you will still need the index of the recipe to delete. You can get it from the outer for-loop by changing this:
for (const recipe of recipes) {

to this:
for (const [i, recipe] of recipes.entries()) {

See here for more info on getting the loop index from a for-loop.
Once you do this I believe your delete button should work.
Edit button
The edit button should work in the exact same way as your delete button. So once you fix delete, you can add the edit button's event listener right after it:
editButton.addEventListener("click", function() { editRecipe(i); })

A note on passing functions
I see from your comment that you tried to directly pass your delete function to addEventListener without success. I assume that means you tried to do something like:
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteRecipe(i)); // this doesn't work

The reason this code doesn't work is because the parenthesis in deleteRecipe(i) means the function is executed right then and there, and its return value (which is undefined) is what is passed to addEventListener.
If you want to pass a function without executing it, you have to just pass its name (no parenthesis):
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteRecipe);

However, deleteRecipe needs the index of the recipe to delete (i). So how do we accomplish this? Well, by doing exactly what you did: making an anonymous function that provides a closure. So your code is actually the right way to do this.
Eventually when you learn arrow notation, you will find a slightly shorter way of doing this:
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => deleteRecipe(i));

